# ASP.NET-CORE-MVC / 2 custom error pages, each one is responsible for only one specified error

Tags: error-handling, asp.net-core-mvc

I use `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` in **Startup.cs** to display any custom exception that my website may have. Now my goal is to make a custom error page that only targets individual errors specified by me.

For example let's say I wrote something in **HomeController.cs** that is going to give me an exception on purpose. I want to make a custom error page only for that specific error, and I want rest of the errors to be handled by `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` like usual.

Now basically I want to do that for 2 specific errors on 2 different pages, so I need to make 2 custom error pages, and each is responsible for one specific error of my choice.

How can I achieve this? That's pretty much it, tell me if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by only using 1 view like this 
First you need to define to let .Net core know how handle error

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/500");
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
   {
      await next();
      if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
      {
         context.Request.Path = "/Error/404";
         await next();
      }
  });
```

So basically I will handle 500, 404 error and redirect it to my Error controller

Then create ErrorController

```
    public class ErrorController: Controller
    {
        private readonly IExceptionHandler _exceptionHandler;
        public ErrorController(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler)
        {
            _exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
        }

        [HttpGet("/Error/{statusCode}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int statusCode)
        {
            if (statusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                var exceptionFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
                var exceptionThatOccurred = exceptionFeature.Error;
                await _exceptionHandler.HandleExceptionAsync(exceptionThatOccurred);
            }
            return View(statusCode);
        }
    }
```

Then finally.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Model;
}
@model int
@{
    var statusCode = Model;
    var statusmessage = "";
    switch (statusCode)
    {
        case 400:
            statusmessage = "Bad request: The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax";
            break;
        case 403:
            statusmessage = "Forbidden: You are not authorize to use system. Please contact admin for detail";
            break;
        case 404:
            statusmessage = "Page not found";
            break;
        case 408:
            statusmessage = "The server timed out waiting for the request";
            break;
        case 500:
            statusmessage = "Internal Server Error";
            break;
        default:
            statusmessage = "That’s odd... Something we didn't expect happened";
            break;
    }
}

<div class="error-page-wrapper row2">
    <div id="error-container" class="clear">
        <div id="error-page" class="clear">
            <div class="hgroup">
                <h1>@statusmessage</h1>
                <h2>@Model Error</h2>
            </div>
            <p>Go <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Back</a> or <a href="/">Home</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So you can see that the if clause handle for 500 error and if you dont want to handle 500 error you can remove it.

Let me know if you have any problem

Comment: Hey man,  after adding: `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/500");
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
   {
      await next();
      if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
      {
         context.Request.Path = "/Error/404";
         await next();
      }
  }); `  in *Startup.cs*,   and creating ErrorController, it gives me this error:  https://imgur.com/a/1Ibn8bG